# SQLite bug with Cyrillic encode

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I'm using the Xamarin SQLite.NET PCL Package. I also have a DB with 1 million records.

The encoding on my source DB is UTF8. For best performance, I chose a FTS engine. Everything works fine, except text with Cyrillic encoding.

Example, the following simple query:

```
"SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name MATCH '"+filter+"*' LIMIT 50";
```

Where `filter` is a string constant with a value. The value depends what user will input from keyboard. (It's like dynamic search)

SO the problem is that I get an SQLite Exception when filter contains a Cyrillic value:

> SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: near " ": syntax error

I tried to something like this: (encode my string query to UTF-8)

```
 string Query = String.Format("SELECT name FROM customer WHERE name MATCH '{0}*' LIMIT 50;",filter);
 Encoding encod = Encoding.UTF8;
 byte[] bts = encod.GetBytes(Query);
 encod = Encoding.Unicode;
 string Output = encod .GetString(bts, 0, bts.Length);
```

But the result is the same!

Any suggestions? What can I do?

Comment: You shouldn't be using string concatenation to build queries. Have you tried this with a parameterized query?

Comment: @RonBeyer i tried with SQLiteCommand _command = _Connection.CreateCommand(Query);
_command.ExecuteQuery<T>(); 
But problem didn't solve,result same!

Comment: Thats not a parameterized query, parameterized queries use placeholders for the values and you use something like `_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filter)`. Google C# parameterized query.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes,i understand you,but these "_command.Parameters" doesnt exist in my current framework (SQLite.Net PCL),or i didn't see.
Okay,thanks...but why with latin words all works fine:) ?

Comment: Might help if you said what the filter value was in order to determine what is going on.

Comment: @RonBeyer its nvm what value(any Cyrillic symbol). I forgot to say that first time query working well,but second+ NOT(for example: i introduced symbol from keyboard "ц",query works and i take correct data from db. Then i introduce second value "к" and filter got now "цк",query is not working well now and i got some corrupt result,and when i introduce third time,application crashes with SQLiteException. SOmething like that)...Thanks!

Comment: *Do not* try to re-encode any strings; when conversion between UTF-16 and UTF-8 is required, the DB driver does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

By now you surely found some solution, but for anyone else this is what the query with SQLite.Net PCL should look like with parameters:

```
string query = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name MATCH @param1 LIMIT 50";
string param = "'your unicode characters'";
conn.execute(query,param);
```

If you have more parameters in your query (eg. @param1, @param2), you separate them with commas, like this:

```
string param = "'your unicode characters','your second parameter'";
```